# Best method to handling exception when using business class in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using one asp.net application where I have business class as mediator between database and application. In my aspx page code behind I am handling exception with log file for every method. Now in my business class I also have some method which is getting called by aspx page.I am also handling exception in the business class method.
Below is my page method example from where I am calling business methods:

```
public void MyPageMethod
{
  BusinessClass bc = new BusinessClass();
  bc.GetData();
}
```

Below is my business class method which is getting called by the page:

```
public string GetData()
{
  string data = string.Empty();
  try
  {
   //some business logic
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {

  }
  return data;
}
```

Now the question here is do I need to handle exception for business class method also?

Comment: Only catch an exception early if you can do something about it.

Comment: No, you will have no exception to handle in your aspx code unless you re-throw it in the BussinessClass.

Comment: @Zohar, I have one query suppose the business method is called from page and this method does not have any exception handling and it will throw some error then that error could be catch by the page method right?

Comment: Why do you need to ask us that? Why not try it yourself?

Comment: I think you are right i am trying it right now.

Comment: Yes, exceptions will bubble up to the first try block.